# Thunderbolt monitor Ethernet adapter causes network preferences pane to crash

Tags: macbook-pro, network, thunderbolt, ethernet

I have a 2014 Macbook Pro 15" running 10.9.3, connected via Thunderbolt to two Apple Thunderbolt monitors.  Each monitor has an Ethernet jack.

The Ethernet seems to pick up an IP address, but doesn't work unless I turn of Wi-Fi, then disconnect my VPN, then pull the Ethernet and reconnect it.

When I plug in my ethernet cable to monitor, the Network Preferences pane crashes every time I open it.

```
6/3/14 2:38:36.962 PM com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[23014]: assertion failed: 13D65: liblaunch.dylib + 25164 [38D1AB2C-A476-385F-8EA8-7AB604CA1F89]: 0x25
6/3/14 2:38:36.971 PM com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[23014]: assertion failed: 13D65: liblaunch.dylib + 25164 [38D1AB2C-A476-385F-8EA8-7AB604CA1F89]: 0x25
6/3/14 2:38:37.130 PM com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[23014]: Bogus event received by listener connection:
<error: 0x7fff785aab50> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff785aae60> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}
6/3/14 2:38:37.235 PM com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[23014]: Could not find image named 'InvalidDataIcon'.
6/3/14 2:38:37.318 PM com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[23014]: -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb8fb502670
6/3/14 2:38:37.319 PM com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[23014]: An uncaught exception was raised
6/3/14 2:38:37.319 PM com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[23014]: -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb8fb502670
6/3/14 2:38:37.320 PM com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[23014]: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c04425c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff887dee75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c04712d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8bfa2322 ___forwarding___ + 1010
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8bfa1ea8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Network                             0x00000001117ea6fd Network + 50941
    6   Network                             0x00000001117ea35d Network + 50013
    7   Network                             0x00000001117e8b6b Network + 43883
    8   Network                             0x00000001118284e7 decryptOldStylePassword + 130098
    9   Network                             0x00000001117e7549 Network + 38217
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c012e0c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
...
)
6/3/14 2:38:37.320 PM com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[23014]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb8fb502670'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c04425c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff887dee75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c04712d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8bfa2322 ___forwarding___ + 1010
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8bfa1ea8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Network                             0x00000001117ea6fd Network + 50941
    6   Network                             0x00000001117ea35d Network + 50013
    7   Network                             0x00000001117e8b6b Network + 43883
    8   Network                             0x00000001118284e7 decryptOldStylePassword + 130098

...    )
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue (10.11.1). It was triggered in my case by plugging an ethernet cable into a 5k iMac that had previously only ever used WiFi. The network preferences pane would hang and `com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice` was shown as taking 100% CPU and "(not responding)" in Activity Monitor.

I tried deleting several network related files in `/Library/Preferences` but the one that seemed to do the trick was `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`. Deleting that file and rebooting allowed me to load Network Preferences, and everything seems good now.

Answer (score 1):

i have had a couple os installs where changing ANY network setting caused the pref pane to crash.  this included enabling disabling ports.  makes no sense, but it doesn't seem unique when i was looking into it.

what i did to fix it was to remove the prefs for the pref pane and start fresh.  it could have something in the plist from a previous device that's messing it up.

i'd suggest removing all interfaces from the network pref pane and adding them again.

if it's more stubborn than that, you can remove the plists, perhaps the ones below:  be sure to leave backups or renamed files and reboot.

> /Library/Managed Preferences/com.apple.networkConnect.plist
>
> /Library/Preferences/com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice.plist

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all /Library/Preferences/ worked for me. I'm now at 59 days of uptime... no crashes from network prefs anymore. 10.9.5 as well.

Comment: That is a really bad idea. First of all: deleting is bad, just rename it. Second: deleting *all* preferences, especially system-wide ones is not a good idea either, it's like a catch-all method that *might* help but will definitely wipe data you might not even know you had (such as iCloud or Back To My Mac keys).

Answer (score -1):

Make a backup and delete all /Library/Preferences/

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Preferences/*
```

Reboot and you should have the problem fixed.... it did work for me... running 10.9.5 beta here.

ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F18

Comment: This is very much the nuclear option… Can you be more specific with which preferences should be deleted as opposed to all of them?

Comment: Please do not suggest this. It's not a solution, it's a catch-all nuke-it-all which *might* help, but always wipes all your settings.